# Pasar un valor string de a una matriz sin repetir Valores VBA

Tags: string, vba, matriz

es mi primera pregunta con uds, pues siempre recurro a esta pagina por algún problema, pero para esto no encuentro solución, tengo un problema con vba y Excel, tengo una hoja que un una determinada columna tiene un string de longitud variable (separados por comas), debo recorrer esa columna unir todas los valores de esa celda y convertirlos en una matriz con valores únicos

Problema 1 : vba me trunca la cadena a 255 caracteres

ejemplo Columna a evaluar "F"

**primer valor encontrado** ="Formula: Enchant Cloak - Lesser Agility, Formula: Enchant Cloak - Greater Resistance, Formula: Enchant Gloves - Greater Strength, Formula: Enchant Weapon - Fiery Weapon, Formula: Enchant Gloves - Advanced Herbalism, Formula: Enchant Boots - Greater Stamina, Formula: Enchant Gloves - Skinning, Formula: Enchant Gloves - Advanced Mining, Formula: Enchant Bracer - Greater Stamina, Formula: Enchant Gloves - Fishing, Formula: Enchant Bracer - Superior Spirit, Formula: Enchant Boots - Spirit, Formula: Enchant Shield - Frost Resistance, Formula: Enchant Gloves - Mining, Formula: Enchant 2H Weapon - Lesser Spirit, Formula: Enchant Boots - Lesser Spirit, Formula: Enchant Boots - Minor Stamina"

**Como Deberá quedar** (extraigo la palabra "Formula: " con replace) "Enchant Cloak - Lesser Agility,Enchant Cloak - Greater Resistance,Enchant Gloves - Greater Strength,Enchant Weapon - Fiery Weapon,Enchant Gloves - Advanced Herbalism,Enchant Boots - Greater Stamina,Enchant Gloves - Skinning,Enchant Gloves - Advanced Mining,Enchant Bracer - Greater Stamina,Enchant Gloves - Fishing,Enchant Bracer - Superior Spirit, Enchant Boots - Spirit,Enchant Shield - Frost Resistance,Enchant Gloves - Mining,Enchant 2H Weapon - Lesser Spirit,Enchant Boots - Lesser Spirit,Enchant Boots - Minor Stamina"

y así sucesivamente con todos los valores encontrados en columna "F" cuyo largo sea mayores a cero y luego esa cadena (enorme), crear una matriz con valores únicos

es decir la matriz (no enumerare todo, pero debería quedar asi:

Array(Enchant Cloak - Lesser Agility,Enchant Cloak - Greater Resistance, .....etc,etc, etc)

Gracias

Comment: Hola, por por aquí que es lo que tienes ya hecho y vamos viendo sobre tú código.

Comment: Hola, tengo un libro de excel compuesto de dos hojas, la primera donde seleciono un criterio profesión, y de acuerdo a esa profesión, debe llenarme un cuadro de lista con las características de esa profesión, dependiendo la profesión (son 6), Google Forms agrega respuestas en diferentes columnas,

Comment: Function FiltrarRecipe(strProf)
 Select Case strProf
   Case "Leatherworking" ' Buscar columna G
      Treg = Worksheets(2).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      sCol = "G"
      strExtraer = "Formula:" 
 End Select
 sRecipe = Null
 For i = 2 To Treg Step 1
    If Len(Worksheets(2).Range(sCol & i).Value) > 0 Then
      temp(UBound(temp)) = sJug
      ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) + 1)
     sRecipe = sRecipe & Worksheets(2).Range(sCol & i) ' ACA ME CORTA CADENA
    End If 
 Next i
 sRecipe = Replace(sRecipe, strExtraer, "", , , vbTextCompare)
 end function

Comment: Las variables estan todas declaradas, solamente que por limitacion de caracteres no las puse, las cadenas son de longitud variable pero muy largas por celda

Comment: No pongas tu código en los comentarios. Edita tu pregunta original y añádelo ahí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías poner tu código y un ejemplo mejor en tu pregunta, porque no queda claro lo que quieres.

Para simularlo, yo he usado tu texto en varias celdas de A

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que uso para crear una matriz de valores únicos:

```
Sub test()

'<<<<<<<<<<<<  AÑADIR REFERENCIA A MICROSODFT.SCRIPTING.RUNTIME
Dim MiMatriz As Variant
Dim STR As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ZZ As Long
Dim MiDict As Dictionary
Dim MyKey As Variant


ZZ = 1
'creamos diccionario para valores únicos
Set MiDict = New Dictionary

Do Until Range("A" & ZZ).Value = ""

    STR = Mid(Range("A" & ZZ).Value, Len("Formula: ") + 1, 99999) 'el texto sin el primer fragmento de Formula:
    MiMatriz = Split(STR, ", Formula: ") 'dividimos por ", Formula: ")


    For i = LBound(MiMatriz) To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
        If MiDict.Exists(MiMatriz(i)) = False Then MiDict.Add MiMatriz(i), 1 'si no existe en el diccionario, lo añadimos
    Next i

    ZZ = ZZ + 1

    Erase MiMatriz
Loop

ReDim MiMatriz(MiDict.Count) As String 'redimensionamos matriz, borrando contenido

i = 0
For Each MyKey In MiDict.Keys 'añadimos valores del diccionario a la matriz
    MiMatriz(i) = MyKey
    i = i + 1
Next MyKey

MiDict.RemoveAll 'borramos diccionario
Set MiDict = Nothing


For i = LBound(MiMatriz) To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    Debug.Print MiMatriz(i)
Next i

Erase MiMatriz


End Sub
```

Básicamente es un bucle a lo largo de la columna A, que celda por celda, divide el contenido, y comprueba con un diccionario si ese valor ya existía o no. Un diccionario es un objeto que solamente permite guardar valores únicos. Y lo usamos para eso.

El output de mi código es:

```
Enchant Cloak - Lesser Agility
Enchant Cloak - Greater Resistance
Enchant Gloves - Greater Strength
Enchant Weapon - Fiery Weapon
Enchant Gloves - Advanced Herbalism
Enchant Boots - Greater Stamina
Enchant Gloves - Skinning
Enchant Gloves - Advanced Mining
Enchant Bracer - Greater Stamina
Enchant Gloves - Fishing
Enchant Bracer - Superior Spirit
Enchant Boots - Spirit
Enchant Shield - Frost Resistance
Enchant Gloves - Mining
Enchant 2H Weapon - Lesser Spirit
Enchant Boots - Lesser Spirit
Enchant Boots - Minor Stamina
```

Adáptalo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es eso lo que necesito, no me da el mismo resultado que a ti, pero lo voy a revisar bien y adaptarlo, no se (como mencione anteriormente es mi primera pregunta ), como dar por respuesta aceptada , mil gracias

Comment: Para aceptarla, marca el check que hay debajo de donde se vota. [MArcar respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)